# Possible to increase UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE on the fly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, libuv

I'm experimenting on multithreading on NodeJS and poking around with the code below

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const start = Date.now();

crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
  console.log('1:', Date.now() - start);
});

crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
  console.log('2:', Date.now() - start);
});

crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
  console.log('3:', Date.now() - start);
});

crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
  console.log('4:', Date.now() - start);
});

crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
  console.log('5:', Date.now() - start);
});
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, by default libuv has a threadpool size of 4 as stated [here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html). So by running the code above, each and every `crypto.pbkdf2` gets assigned to individual thread and run at the same time, while the fifth will wait for awhile to run. Below is the result

```js
1: 484
2: 490
3: 490
4: 490
5: 963
```

I can understand the fifth `crypto.pbkdf2` double the time due to out of threads to be running parallel, so now I'm exploring increasing the thread pool size. Below is my attempt but the result seems to be identical?

```js
$ set UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=120 && node threads.js 

2: 487
3: 492
1: 493
4: 493
5: 986
```

Comment: Put your heavy CPU tasks in a seperate child process, and run *n* child proccess to run your code parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify if you've indeed successfully set the environment variable by simply `console.log(process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE)`, and if you do, you'll realize that it is `undefined`.

The problem is with how you invoke your command, it should be as below instead

```js
UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=120 node threads.js
```